# Atlas does not render images in order[libGDX]

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using the following class to render an atlas on screen:

```
public class AnimationDemo implements ApplicationListener {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private TextureAtlas textureAtlas;
    private Animation animation;
    private float elapsedTime = 0;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/packOne.atlas"));
        animation = new Animation(1 / 1f, textureAtlas.getRegions());
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        textureAtlas.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        //sprite.draw(batch);
        elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

I am a beginner with libGDX, however with the above program my images are not rendered in order as random images appear. I was earlier using the following with the same . atlas file and it was working properly:

```
public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private TextureAtlas textureAtlas;
    private Sprite sprite;
    private int currentFrame = 1;
    private String currentAtlasKey = new String("0001");

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/packOne.atlas"));
        TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion region = textureAtlas.findRegion("0001");
        sprite = new Sprite(region);


        sprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - sprite.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - sprite.getHeight() / 2);
        sprite.scale(4.5f);
        Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                currentFrame++;
                if (currentFrame > 393)
                    currentFrame = 1;

                // ATTENTION! String.format() doesnt work under GWT for god knows why...
                currentAtlasKey = String.format("%04d", currentFrame);
                sprite.setRegion(textureAtlas.findRegion(currentAtlasKey));
            }
        }
                , 0, 1 / 30.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        textureAtlas.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        sprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

Any hints about what might be wrong here?

I am also trying to adapt my program with [Screen Viewport](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/ScreenViewport.html) any headings as in how to implement this would also be welcome.

Edit: The .atlas file is located [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/17c168c67d8dbb53874d)

Comment: Does it animate every seconds as expected or does it change images every frame?

Comment: Its changing images every frame, random

Comment: try to print the frame number of the animation to see if there is an ambiguity there and then match the sequence manually with ur frames to be confirm that its problem with animation

Comment: That is a nice idea, I will do that now and report back

Comment: I ran the example with an atlas containing 5 images: 01.png, 02.png, etc. The result was as expected, the images were displayed every second in order. There's something else going on here as your code is perfectly fine.

Comment: Exactly, I am running the same atlas with different code as mentioned above and the code for which is given it works fine there too. I am unable to debug further though.

Comment: You are right, this should be okay. It seems to me that there must be something with the atlas file. Could you show that us?

Comment: To note I was autogening the atlas file with the command `TexturePacker.process("../../texture-packer2","packed","pack2");` The first arg is the dir of your individual images to pack, I put a pack.json file in that directory for settings manipulation. The second arg is the output dir. The third is the name of the pack file and atlas. Are you manipulating your pack.atlas file manually?

Comment: No I am using GDX Texture packer to automate this process. I am adding the .atlas file above - bear with me its a bit huge.

Comment: Still thinking about it... I could make a workaround, but I still think the atlas file should be fixed.

Comment: What are you base image file names?

Comment: They start from 0001 till 0392

Comment: So I have found some discussions about this random ordered atlas regions problem, and I'm not sure this could work, but you could try to create a settings.json for the texturepacker(as a last parameter), with the property gird set to true: {grid: true}

Comment: The problem is, I couldn't reproduce this in my environment, because my atlas file is always sorted regardless the grid parameters value.

Comment: This was the first forum post: http://esotericsoftware.com/forum/Texture-Packer-not-creating-spritesheet-in-correct-order-1686

Comment: And this was linked on that page:   http://esotericsoftware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=9843#p9843

Comment: Let me check on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your atlas file isn't ordered. If you call the code below, it will be ordered.

```
regions.sort(new Comparator<AtlasRegion>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(AtlasRegion o1, AtlasRegion o2) {
                return Integer.parseInt(o1.name) > Integer.parseInt(o2.name) ? 1 : -1;
            }
        });
```

But I'm still checking why your atlas regions isn't ordered.

Comment: I though Animation class sorted it for you.

Comment: In the getTextures method, they say the returned objects are unordered. For getRegions they don't state anything. And as I experienced with javadocs, if something isn't stated specifically by the developers, then you can't count on that :D

Comment: What I don't get is that it is verbatim this example: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/12/09/LibGDX-Tutorial-3B-Simple-Animation.aspx and obviously someone doesn't post a tutorial like that with an unordered array on their hands.

Comment: textureAtlas.getRegions() but the sort is a void method, so you need a local variable for this.

Comment: Solved! You my champ bro!

Comment: What about using the built in index comparator?

Comment: I didn't try that, but I tried to compare the regions by index, and it seems to me, that indices are always ordered. So img_02, img_01,img_03 in atlas file will have index 1-3.

Answer (score 1):

you should create array with frames ordered alphabetically instead of using **textureAtlas.getRegions()** which just gives you an array without caring of order.

The example for atlas with regions named like: **region1**, **region2** and so on would be:

```
    AtlasRegion[] frames = new AtlasRegion[framesCount];

    for(int i = 0; i < framesCount; i++)
    {
        frames[i] = atlas.findRegion("region" + i);
    }
```

so you can adjust it to your regions names.

If you want to get all frames from textureAtlas you can also do it like this:

```
    Array<String> names = new Array<String>();

    for(AtlasRegion region : textureAtlas.getRegions())
    {
        names.add( region.name );
    }

    names.sort();

    Array<AtlasRegion> frames = new Array<AtlasRegion>();

    for(String s : names)
    {
        frames.add( textureAtlas.findRegion(s) );
    }
```

and then after get frames array just create animation object:

```
    animation = new Animation(1/1f, frames.items); //or just frames depending on which type frames is
```

Comment: textureAtlas performs a sort when you initialize the atlas, see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas.java

Comment: yup of course it is **but on the id not the name** - see the indexComparator Comparator instance in the code you've shared

Comment: If all the indexes are -1 how is that a good method for sorting, in other words why did they sort by index instead of by name? I suppose you could extend the class to have different sort methods.

Comment: I found it! a better way at least. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#image-indexes so you just underscore the frame numbers and the index is generated.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate :)

Answer (score 1):

TexturePacker will index the images for you as long as you follow the naming scheme set forth here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#image-indexes.

so your frames would be named something like

```
anim1_001.png
anim1_002.png
...
anim1_100.png
```

and a separate animation would simply be

```
anim2_001.png
....
anim2_100.png
```

EDIT:

additionally you can get the regions only related to certain animations. So instead of

```
animation = new Animation(1 / 1f, textureAtlas.getRegions());
```

you could use (yes it's `findRegions()` not `findRegion()`):

```
animation1 = new Animation(1 / 1f, textureAtlas.findRegions("anim1"));
animation2 = new Animation(1 / 1f, textureAtlas.findRegions("anim2"));
```

EDIT2:

If you're are using a stage it is quite easy to implement a screen viewport. I do it like this, (stage is a field and this step is in the show/create method):

```
stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
```

Then in the resize method:

```
stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
```

Without a stage it's only slightly more complex

```
camera = new WhateverCamera();
viewport = new ScreenViewport(camera);
```

Then in the resize method:

```
viewport.update(width, height, true);
```

Use whatever camera you want, WhateverCamera is a placeholder and can be OrthographicCamera or PerspectiveCamera. 
The last argument `true` centers the camera, if you don't want to do this set it to false or leave it out, it assumes false.

Comment: I read about the image indices, but if you check the tutorial that you mentioned, they use image names like 001-010 not name_001-name_010. That is another strange thing:S

Comment: @gaRos, Yes good catch!  That tutorial missed the mark on that.